# Adding a Label to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Class {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Establishing the JFrame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Application");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(800, 500);
    //adding labels
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label Text", JLabel.RIGHT);
    label1.setText("Today's Task");
    label1.setVisible(true);
    label1.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
  }
}
```

I have looked into creating a label for a JFrame but for some reason I am just bamboozled. If someone could please enlighten me as to why my label is not appearing in my JFrame please do because I am confused... Thank you! I am new to coding so I do apologize for asking such a simple easy question.

Comment: You forgot to add your label into your frame

Comment: Thank you sir! I think I just need to get use to programming and its syntax and I feel bad for asking such simple questions but I guess thats how you learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add your `JLabel` to your `JFrame`.

```
frame.add(label1);
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you created a new Label,you should add it to frame.Then only that label will display on the frame

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label Text", JLabel.RIGHT);
label1.setText("Today's Task");
label1.setVisible(true);
label1.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
//Adding label1 to frame
frame.add(label1);
```